# String replace with =&nbsp; with empty string PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am having some typical problems with string replace.

First of all, I am getting a 'Rich Text Format' on HTML by using [Tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com)

Then , i process the HTML string with `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);`

But, when i echo the values from database, there are random strings containing '= '. I tried removing it by

**PHP:**

```
html_entity_decode($d1);
str_replace('= ','', $d1);
preg_replace('= ','', $d1);
preg_replace('/&#61;&#32;/','',$d1);
str_replace('&#61;&#32;','',$d1);
```

& by **Jquery**

```
$('#descc').text(function (i, old) {
     return old
         .replace('/= /', ' ');
});
```

but no use.

Please help...you can check the description [HERE](http://gcdc2013-agrinova.appspot.com/v2/idea/12#Hydraulic%20Grease%20Gun%20-%20can%20they%20change%20?)

Comment: Check the encoding. Ensure to have UTF-8 everywhere. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to use `\s+` that replace one or more spaces

```
preg_replace('/=\s+/i','', $d1);
```

or better to use:

```
preg_replace('/=(\s|&nbsp;)+/i','', $d1);
```

It's replace more than one and space and `&nbsp;` characters.